# How to search in all databases having `in use` table

Tags: php, mysql, centos

My database server has been damaged recently and I have more than 300 databases in the server.

The way I'm currently doing is to run `phpmyadmin` and check all databases one by one to see if any database has at least one database with `in use` in `collation` to restore.

How to search for `collation` in all databases and tables having at least one `in use` in `collation`?

Server is CentOS 7 and I have root access. I can run PHP script if needed if you can help me with PHP.

**Update 1**

Until now I have found I should run these query to use database and show table status:

```
Use DatabaseName;
show TABLE STATUS;
```

It shows all tables status, including the corrupted ones:

```
| 2022-04-05 20:31:19 | utf8_persian_ci   |     NULL |                |                                                                  | 288230376151710720 | N         |
| users            | NULL   |    NULL | NULL       | NULL |           NULL |        NULL |              NULL |         NULL |      NULL |           NULL | NULL                | NULL| NULL                | NULL              |     NULL | NULL           | Table 'db_name.users' doesn't exist in engine            |               NULL | NULL      |
```

And I need to either `grep` or pipe it to another file to check and list all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can modify this shell script for your use:

mysql -N suppress header
grep -v E "..|.." exclude system databases

```
root@localhost:~# mysql -N -e "SHOW DATABASES" | grep -v -E "mysql|information_schema|performance_schema" |
> while read dbs
> do
>   echo "CHECK DATABASE " $dbs
>. # your command
> done
```

output:

```
CHECK DATABASE  bernd
CHECK DATABASE  sys
```

with 2 commands:

```
mysql -N -e "SHOW DATABASES" | grep -v -E "mysql|information_schema|performance_schema" |
while read dbs
do
  echo "CHECK DATABASE " $dbs;
  mysql -N -e "USE $dbs; SHOW TABLE STATUS;"
done
```

Comment: i have add it in my answer

Comment: Yes, thanks. Just to note that in the first command, please replace `$db` with `$dbs` in `echo "CHECK DATABASE " $db`